# Issue with posting on business page of facebook using c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms

I have read many many articles tonight and still do not understood what I shoud do to post on business page of facebook. Here is my code:

```
string token = getHtml("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=clientID&client_secret=secretKey&grant_type=client_credentials");
token = token.Replace("access_token=", "");
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(token);
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args["message"] = "Testing 12qwe3";
fbClient.Post("/pageID/feed", args);
```

It always says app not authorized. How to authorize it? I read so many articles, but still not able to do it.

I am posting this after totally failing from researching many articles. Kindly let me know whats wrong?

**----UPDATE**

I did the first part,  by making myself the manager page and then creating an app and then providing that app the ability to manage pages and publish etc...but again another issue when i do so even using the above code i still get the same error.But when i use the tools (**GRAPH API EXPLORER**) portion of facebook site and select this app and generate a token .I than use that directly in app and it posts fine. Kinldy let me know whats wrong!